# What is the equivalent to the deprecated $(InputDir) Macro?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor

Trying to set up a custom pre-processor for a single file, I tried to use

```
"$(testDir)test.exe" "$(InputPath)" "$(ProjectDir)model.c"
```

As the command line.
But `"$(InputPath)` is deprecated in Visual Studio 2013, and I do not know how replace this with a non-deprecated macro.

Comment: Have you tried $(ProjectPath)?

Comment: @rrirower Yes but I need the path of the file, which should go in the "pre-processor".